# Endless Loop for Finding the RSS

Tags: c#, winforms, linear-regression

When I tried to calculate RSS everything seems fine I check with debug and it was okay after that I downgraded to values of for loops but even then the program didn't finish.When ı started to program WindowsForm doesn't respond and I searched for solutions and found a code about open new threads.But nothing's changed.In conclusion the program endless either.Thanks for your cooperation.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    var count = 0;
    double RSS = 0;
    double RSS2 = 0;
    int W1 = 0;
    int W0 = 0;
    int xi = 0;
    int a = 0;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {


        for (int w0 = 100000; w0 <= 150000; w0 = +10000)
        {
            UIupdate(w0);
            count = w0;
            for (int w1 = -10; w1 <= 10; w1++)
            {
                for (a = 0; a < 100; a++)
                {
                    RSS = Math.Tan(w1) * column1[a] + w0;


                    if (RSS2 == 0)
                    {
                        RSS2 = RSS;
                        W1 = w1;
                        W0 = w0;
                        xi = a;
                    }

                    if (RSS2 > RSS)
                    {

                        RSS2 = RSS;
                        W1 = w1;
                        W0 = w0;
                        xi = a;

                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
    );

    button1.Enabled = true;
    button2.Enabled = false;
        label7.Text = RSS2.ToString();
        label8.Text = W0.ToString();
        label9.Text = W1.ToString();
        label10.Text = column1[xi].ToString();


}
private void UIupdate(int w0)
{
    var timenow = DateTime.Now;
    if ((DateTime.Now - dt).Milliseconds<=50)
    {


        synchronizationcontext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(o => {

            label1.Text = "first intercept point: " + (int)o; 
        return;



        }),w0);
        dt = timenow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to add a Application.DoEvents(); inside your UIupdate method. It should work.

Assuming that you calling a method that is updating the UI even inside a task, it will invoke that method to run in the main thread... That's why your application freeze.

Another suggestion is to remove the async/await keywords and then move your rest of the code to a task using the method ContinuesWith from your created task.